# ELKI: How to create Database from several files in java

Tags: java, file, elki

I try to get data from several csv files. I use ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection for db

```
Database getDbFromFiles(List<File> files) {
    ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
    params.addParameter(ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection.Parameterizer.PARSER_ID, files);
    Database db = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(StaticArrayDatabase.class, params);
return db;
    }
```

like for FileBasedDatabaseConnection

```
ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
params.addParameter(FileBasedDatabaseConnection.Parameterizer.INPUT_ID, filename);
Database db = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(StaticArrayDatabase.class, params);
```

but when i run i get error

> de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.UnspecifiedParameterException:
>   No value given for parameter "dbc.in": Expected: The name of the input
>   file to be parsed.
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.utilities.optionhandling.WrongParameterValueException:
>   Wrong value of parameter dbc.parser. Read:
>   [src\main\resources\data1.csv, src\main\resources\data2.csv,
>   src\main\resources\data3.csv]. Expected: Parser to provide the
>   database. Implementing de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.Parser

Maybe someone worked with several files on ELKI and knew how
to do it right. I did not find the code to handle multiple files in ELKI

Answer (score 1):

You set the **parser** to a `List<File>`. That cannot work.

A parser is a program routine that interprets the input of some (text) data stream.

You need to set the right parameter (the input file name, not the parser).

https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/709dbfa01b40ad023885b0745bad2f26184a4ac7/elki-input/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/datasource/ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection.java#L164

Comment: I don`t understand. The code you gave is only one row in method of ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection class. To run it this class object required. Parameters of constructor **ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection(List<File> files, Parser parser, List<ObjectFilter> filters)**  is **Parser** and **filters** which unknown. 

The input file name not allowed  in Parameterizer because Parametrizer in ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection extends **AbstractDatabaseConnection.Parameterizer** in which FILTERS_ID and PARSER_ID allowed and input file name is absent.

Comment: That code is not what you need to do, but the code that you are already calling! You need to set the *file list* parameter, not the parser parameter. You can easily find the correct option ID if you look at the source code of ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection.

Comment: I looked. There is no such parameter. Only FILTERS_ID and PARSER_ID . I can`t set INPUT_FILES or INPUT_ID parameter on ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConnection.  Is it really so difficult to give the string with the correct code? So far, I see that it seems that for ConcatenateFilesDatabaseConcession simply did not write Parameterizer

Comment: The correct option ID can be seen **in the source code line I linked** to above. It currently re-uses the option from another class, so the auto completion of the IDE cannot find it.